# Laravel, multiple queries nesting with multiple order by

Tags: laravel, nested, eloquent, subquery

I am using Laravel 5.2. 
I have 3 tables (models):

- Events
- Dates
- Sessions

My relations: Event hasMany Dates. Date hasMany Sessions.
The problem is that when i get the event with dates and session, the data are not ordered.

How can I get Event with ordered dates and every date with ordered sessions.

```
$event = Event::find($id);
$event->load(['dates' => function($query)
    {
        $query->orderBy('date', 'asc');
    }
]);
```

**This is how i get an event with ordered dates. How to order sessions for every date?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess i've found the answer. The load didn't work inside the nested query. So i should use 'with' not 'load'.

```
$event = Event::find($id);
$event->load(['dates' => function($query)
            {   
                $query->with(['sessions' => function($query)
                                  {   
                                      $query->orderBy('starts_at', 'asc');
                                  }
                ])->orderBy('date', 'asc');
            }
    ]);
```